# Экранировать путь к файлу

Tags: python

Не могу нормально собрать путь к файлу, вот это рабочий код

```
path_new_pdf = os.path.join(r'\\corp\docs\falcon', 'filename.jpg')
```

А вот это не рабочий код, так как в строке dirpath есть слеши

```
dirpath = '\\corp\docs\falcon'
path_new_pdf = os.path.join(dirpath, 'filename.jpg')
```

Как экранировать символы в переменной dirpath. dirpath получаю из другой функции и сделать вот так нельзя:

```
dirpath = r'\\corp\docs\falcon'
path_new_pdf = os.path.join(dirpath, 'filename.jpg')
```

Comment: Почему нельзя `r'\\corp\docs\falcon'`? Без суффикса `r` у вас строка будет неправильной: `print('\\corp\docs\falcon')` выведет `\corp\docsalcon`, т.к. произойдет преобразование символов

Comment: Вы ведь видели как на строки в коде влияет `\n` (символ перевода строки)? `\f` тоже особенный это `ASCII Formfeed (FF)` (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) поэтому с ним ваш путь, объявленный в коде, будет невалидный
Поэтому, нужно `r` добавлять или добавлять \ к каждому слешу, типа: `'\\corp\\docs\\falcon'`.
А так, откуда тот путь берет та функция из которой `dirpath` приходит?

Comment: Не страдайте фигней. Используйте `pathlib`

Comment: Пусть вам передают нормальный `dirpath`, если это готовая переменная, то вы не должны ни о чём заботиться. А если там уже сломаны бэкслэши, то это не ваша проблема, то тех, кто вам кривое значение передаёт. Покажите, что пишет `print(dirpath)`, который вам передали. И напечатайте свой `dirpath`, который вы сами присваиваете, чтобы вы знали, как он должен выглядеть на печати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('C:/Windows')
# Если strick = True то при отсутствии объекта по этому пути бросит исключение 
print(p.resolve(strict=True))
# C:\Windows
```

И не надо будет ничего экранировать

```py
# Текущая папка
e = Path('.')
print(e)
# Полный путь к текущей папке
print(e.resolve())
print(Path('C:/Users/user/Storage/Projects/Python/test'))
print(Path('C:/Users/user/Storage/Projects/Python/test').joinpath('filename.jpg'))
# .
# C:\Users\user\Storage\Projects\Python\test
# C:\Users\user\Storage\Projects\Python\test
# C:\Users\user\Storage\Projects\Python\test\filename.jpg
```

Ну и так [далее](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

> *На самом деле либа очень юзабельна, от души рекомендую*

Comment: Еще так можно `Path('C:/Users/user/Storage/Projects/Python/test') / 'filename.jpg'` :)

Comment: `e = Path('.')` это не текущая папка, а текущая рабочая директория, для текущей папки скрипта: `Path(__file__).resolve().parent`. Например, если вы открыли консоль в папке `C:\Users`, то это рабочая директория и если выполните скрипт из `C:/Users/user/Storage/Projects/Python/test`, то `.` вернет `C:\Users`

Comment: Использовал такую форму. Спасибо большое! path_new_pdf = Path(dirpath).joinpath('filename.jpg')